# OpenCV InputArray and getMat method

Tags: c++, opencv

I expend a lot of time with it and seems something strange happening with `cv::Mat`, `cv::Vec` and `cv::InputArray`.

`cv::EM` requires and InputArray with only 1 channel if I define `SampleType` as `cv::Vec` or `cv::Matx` and `SampleContainerType` as `cv::Mat_` and populate it, all is correct, m_Samples have correct structure and 1 channel. When the samples arrive as `InputArray` to EM [em.cpp#L83](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/ef91d7e8830c36785f0b6fdbf2045da48413dd76/modules/ml/src/em.cpp#L83) it turns magically to 2 channels matrix.

I want to use `cv::Matx` or `cv::Vec` instead of `cv::Mat` to allow user to define easily the samples like `SampleType(1., 2.)`

I created this file https://gist.github.com/jrdi/9328183 to test combinations and I don't understand what is wrong with the first two approaches. In addition, I don't want to recreate each sample like in last example.

**Edit (added code as requested):**

```
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "itkObject.h"
#include "itkObjectFactory.h"

#include "BoostTestTargetConfig.h"

void CheckInputArrayChannels( cv::InputArray samples )
{
  cv::Mat matrix = samples.getMat();
  if( matrix.channels() != 1 )
  {
    itkGenericExceptionMacro( << "Channels error." );
  }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( cxInputArrayTest )
{
  const unsigned int Dimension = 2;
  typedef double CoordinateType;
  // FAILS
  {
    typedef cv::Vec<CoordinateType, Dimension> SampleType;
    typedef cv::Mat_<CoordinateType>           SampleContainerType;

    SampleType sample(2., 1.);
    SampleContainerType samples;
    samples.push_back( sample.t() );

    BOOST_CHECK( samples.channels() == 1 );
    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( CheckInputArrayChannels( samples ) );
  }
  // FAILS
  {
    typedef cv::Matx<CoordinateType, 1, Dimension> SampleType;
    typedef cv::Mat_<CoordinateType>               SampleContainerType;

    SampleType sample(2., 1.);
    SampleContainerType samples;
    samples.push_back( sample );

    BOOST_CHECK( samples.channels() == 1 );
    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( CheckInputArrayChannels( samples ) );
  }
  // FAILS
  {
    typedef cv::Matx<CoordinateType, 1, Dimension> SampleType;
    typedef std::vector<SampleType>                SampleContainerType;

    SampleType sample(2., 1.);
    SampleContainerType samples;
    samples.push_back( sample );

    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( CheckInputArrayChannels( samples ) );
  }
  // PASS
  {
    cv::Mat sample(1, 2, cv::DataType<CoordinateType>::type);
    sample.at<CoordinateType>(0) = 2.;
    sample.at<CoordinateType>(1) = 1.;

    cv::Mat_<CoordinateType> samples;
    samples.push_back( sample );

    BOOST_CHECK( samples.channels() == 1 );
    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( CheckInputArrayChannels( samples ) );
  }
  // PASS
  {
    typedef cv::Matx<CoordinateType, 1, Dimension> SampleType;
    typedef cv::Mat_<CoordinateType>               SampleContainerType;

    SampleType sample(2., 1.);
    SampleContainerType samples;
    samples.push_back( cv::Mat(sample) );

    BOOST_CHECK( samples.channels() == 1 );
    BOOST_CHECK_NO_THROW( CheckInputArrayChannels( samples ) );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OpenCV reference:-

```
Vec: Template class for short numerical vectors, a partial case of Matx.
...
The Vec class is commonly used to describe pixel types of multi-channel arrays
```

So you are creating multi-channel rows when you push `cv::Vec` into a `Mat`.

Your last example is the correct way to create multi-dimensional matrix.
By default the data will be copied when you use

```
cv::Mat(sample)
```

You can create reference to `sample` by passing `false` to `Mat` constructor.

```
cv::Mat(sample, false)
```

More reference on how number of channels is computed (rows * cols) :-

```
template<typename _Tp, int m, int n> class Matx
{
public:
    typedef _Tp value_type;
    typedef Matx<_Tp, (m < n ? m : n), 1> diag_type;
    typedef Matx<_Tp, m, n> mat_type;
    enum { depth = DataDepth<_Tp>::value, rows = m, cols = n, channels = rows*cols,
       type = CV_MAKETYPE(depth, channels) };
  ....
 };
```

Comment: IMHO when the reference guide said "commonly used to describe pixel type" they are talking about `cv::Vec2b`, `cv::Vec3d`,... and common used types in multi-channel matrix defined like `cv::Matx<uchar, 2, 1>` or `cv::Vec<uchar, 2>` all are single-channel arrays that you can use like `cv::Mat_<cv::Vec2b>` to generate multi-channel arrays. When I do it like `cv::Matx<double, n, m>` or `cv::Vec<double, n>` I am defining one-channel arrays.

Comment: It is not intuitive but test it and you will see how many channels Matx<uchar, 2, 1> creates (it is two). Added snippets from class Matx.

Comment: ok, thank you so much I saw you are right but I don't understand why OpenCV generate rows*cols channels by default.

Comment: *By default the data will be copied* -- isn't by default `copyData = false`?

Comment: Look at the doc here http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#gsc.tab=0            .    The constructor which takes Matx specifically:     Mat (const Matx< _Tp, m, n > &mtx, bool copyData=true)